# /&error=invalidkey when resetting password in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, passwords

I get this WordPress error when resetting password

So I clicked the lost password, got the email, clicked the link, but the link shows this:

> `/&error=invalidkey`

It then cycles back to the reset page.

I have already disabled caching plugins.

Comment: Improved syntax and formatting.

Comment: hi! what i mean is the automatic mailer. it cycles back to resetting password page. it does not go to the page where one can input a new password.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following link, that mentions different ways to change your password, can help:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

Comment: hi! what i mean is the automatic mailer. it cycles back to resetting password page. it does not go to the page where one can input a new password.